# Changing form action based on selected value

Tags: custom-field, actions, forms

I am making a form using elementor pro.
Is it possible to take an action following an user's choice?

p.e.

Question "Which Item do you prefer?"
radiobutton1 - first item
radiobutton2 - second item
radiobutton3 - third item

if the user selects radiobutton1 --> do nothing
if the user selects radiobutton2 --> open a time field
if the user selects radiobutton3 --> open a date and time field

Comment: You should ask this question over on the Elementor site, either in their community forums or via Support: https://elementor.com/ This Stack Exchange is meant for more general WordPress questions as plugins, especially paid plugins, should have their own plugin-specific support channels that will be more helpful.

Comment: @Michelle I've already done that but they don't answer.

Comment: You may want to consider a different plugin / theme customizer if their paid support is unresponsive. (An alternative option would be to install a custom form builder plugin such as Gravity Forms, Formidable, Forminator, WP Forms, Contact Form 7 or Ninja Forms. Those are all built to do more customized form-building than a theme-focused plugin like Elementor is made for.) But no matter what this Stack Exchange won't be the place to find the answer to any plugin-specific question, as it's focused on core WordPress questions. Best of luck to you!